# Problems creating lots of thumbnails using AVAssetImageGenerator with ARC

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, automatic-ref-counting, thumbnails

I've looked through every list I can find for ideas on this but have been stuck for a couple of days now so here's hoping...

I'm trying to create a lot of video thumbnails (100 or so) at once using AVAssetImageGenerator.
While testing I'm always using the same movie files, but the process (seemingly) randomly  succeeds or fails, plus I now get all the movies loaded into physical memory at once which I don't want. I'm obviously doing something wrong but cannot figure out what - and under ARC can't manually manage the memory.

Background;
It's an AVFoundation video player using ARC (Xcode 4.2.1, OSX 10.7.2, MBP 2.4GHz i5, 4GB RAM).
It has a playlist style interface allowing you to drag folders of movie files to it. It recurses through the paths it's given and plucks out the valid movies and adds them to the list.
Movies are represented by a Movie class which has an AVAsset member variable (movieAsset) initialised with the file path.  So far so good - everything works, movies can be played, only the movie being played is in physical memory.
I've added a -createThumbnail method to the Movie class which is called in the Movie's init method (code snippet below).
With the addition of this code I'm getting a few behaviours I  can't eradicate - none of which occur if I don't call the -createThumbnail code below.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

1. Every movie added to the playlist is now being loaded into physical memory immediately - so the apps memory footprint has gone way up (without thumbnail code = 40MB for 100 movies, with thumbnails (NSImages at 32x18 pixels) 750MB for the same 100 movies).
2. Looking at Activity Monitor->Open Files and Ports, all the movie files are listed even after thumbnail creation has finished.  This didn't occur before - only the movie being played was listed.
3. Thumbnail creation completely locks up my machine until it's complete - even though I'm calling AVAssetImageGenerator within an asynchronous block - (CPU usage never gets above 35%).  Could this be a disk access problem trying to read 100 movies at once?
4. Thumbnail creation is very erratic.  Sometimes all thumbnails are created, but often a random 30-70% are not.  Maybe also a disk access problem?

I'm very new to OOP and Obj-C so have probably made a newbies mistake - but I just can't track it down...

Also worth noting that the "Error creating thumbnail" and "Error finding duration" NSLogs are never called...

```
-(void)createThumbnail{
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"duration"];
        [movieAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {
            NSError *error = nil;
            AVKeyValueStatus valueStatus = [movieAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"duration" error:&error];
            switch (valueStatus) {
                case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
                    if ([movieAsset tracksWithMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:movieAsset];
                        Float64 movieDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds([movieAsset duration]);
                        CMTime middleFrame = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(movieDuration/2.0, 600);

                        CGImageRef imageForThumbnail = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:middleFrame actualTime:NULL error:NULL];

                        if (imageForThumbnail != NULL) {                            
                            NSSize sizeOption = NSMakeSize(32, 18);
                            self.thumbnail = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageForThumbnail size:sizeOption];
                            NSLog(@"Thumbnail created for %@", [self filenameString]);
                        }
                        else{
                            NSLog(@"-----Error creating thumbnail for %@", [self filenameString]);
                        }
                        CGImageRelease(imageForThumbnail);
                    }
                    break;
                case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Error finding duration");
                    break;
                case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled finding duration");
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }
```

(Note: I've been using the same few folders of movie files to develop the app for the last month or so.  They're all local valid files that play successfully in the app.  Some of these folders dropped contain over a hundred movie files nested within various subfolders).

Many thanks if anyone can help.
Chas.

Comment: I'm not sure here but I'm doing something similar and instead of "duration" I am watching "status". I got some code from elsewhere and it's not using  loadValuesAsync... but instead using a KVO observing method to observe the "status" keyPath of a AVPlayerItem instance (there will be many instances as I have one for each cell in a collection view) - but the problem is pretty much the same and I'm just guessing that watching status or duration could might make a difference. I am not seeing a lot of errors, however I'm seeing lockups, likely cause I'm not using background loading yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had some weird issues when using `AVAssetImageGenerator` in this way as well (on iOS at least). It seems to me at least to be somewhat broken when used in combination with the blocks/GCD API. Rather than loading everything asynchronously, try making a single queue/loop that operates in a single background thread, and walk through the movies that way. This should also help to keep your memory usage down.